If $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, then $f^n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n\;n!}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^{n+1}}\sin((n+1)\cot^{-1}x)$
Please help with this derivation.

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$, then
$$f^n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n\;n!}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^{n+1}}\sin\left((n+1)\cot^{-1}x\right)$$

(Note: @Blue updated the old-style factorial notation when transcribing the original image.)
Can someone please explain how is the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)$ coming to this. I cannot get any clue how is the $n$-th derivative coming to that.
Please help.

Typically $n$-the derivative is denoted by $f^{(n)}$ and $f^n$ means either composition power or pointwise multiplication power, depending on context. It's probably not pointwise. What is the notation $\lfloor n$, though?

Take a few derivatives, see if it matches the given result. If yes, formulate your induction hypothesis and try to prove the general case. If equality holds in general, it should work out.

@AlvinL: In this case, $f^n$ does indeed appear to be the $n$-th derivative. (Mathematica verifies the formula.) The box notation is an old-style factorial. (Perhaps the $f^{(n)}$ notation hadn't come into style?)

I would start with $\sin (\cot^{-1} x) = \frac {1}{\sqrt {1+x^2}}$ and $\sin (2\cot^{-1} x) = \frac {2x}{1+x^2}$ and unpack what the expression on the right really says.

We know that the Taylor series contains the derivatives
$$
f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}h^n+...
$$
So if we get the series expansion in powers of $h$ in another way, we can identify the derivatives.
Use partial decomposition with the complex unit to apply the binomial theorem,
$$
2f(x)=\frac1{1-ix}+\frac1{1+ix},\\
2f(x+h)=\frac1{(1-ix)(1-\frac{ih}{1-ix})}+\frac1{(1+ix)(1+\frac{ih}{1+ix})}.
$$
Now we can apply geometric series, assuming e.x. $|h|<1\le\sqrt{1+x^2}$ to get convergence in the otherwise formal manipulations.
So currently
$$
2f(x+h)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac{i^n}{(1-ix)^{n+1}}+\frac{(-i)^n}{(1+ix)^{n+1}}\right]h^n.
$$
In principle the task is solved, but we'd like to find a real form of these expressions, as obviously the sum of conjugate complex numbers gives twice the real part. Combine the powers in nominator and denominator,
$$
2f(x+h)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left[\frac{i}{(i+x)^{n+1}}+\frac{-i}{(i-x)^{n+1}}\right]h^n.
$$
Now switch to a polar form $i+x=re^{i\phi}$, $r=\sqrt{1+x^2}$, $\cot(\phi)=x$
$$
2f(x+h)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left[\frac{ie^{-i(n+1)\phi}}{r^{n+1}}+\frac{-ie^{i(n+1)\phi}}{r^{n+1}}\right]h^n,\\
f(x+h)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{r^{n+1}}\sin((n+1)\phi)h^n.
$$
and read off the claimed form of the derivatives.

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$, then
$$f^n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n\;n!}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^{n+1}}\sin\left((n+1)\cot^{-1}x\right)$$

Just a general idea
$$f^{1}(x)=-\frac{2x}{\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{2}}$$
$$f^{2}(x)=\frac{2 \left(3x^{2} - 1\right)}{\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{3}}$$
$$f^{3}(x)=-\frac{24x \left(x^{2} - 1\right)}{\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{4}}$$
$$f^{4}(x)=\frac{24 \left(5x^{4} - 10x^{2} + 1\right)}{\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{5}}$$
On surface level observation, we can deduce that for $n$ being odd there is a $(-1)$ and for even there is a $1$, basically a $(-1)^n$ term and in the denominator the $1+x^2$ factor is of multiplicity $k(n+1)$ form,
We can roughly say,
$$f^{n}(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{(1+x^2)^{k(n+1)}}\cdots$$

We have, $$x^2+1=0\implies (x+i)(x-i)=0$$
We then perform partial fraction split using the above idea,
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{1}{x-i} - \frac{1}{x+i}  \right] $$
$$f(x)= \frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{1}{x-i} - \frac{1}{x+i}  \right]$$
By induction, one can easily prove (refer the general idea method);
$$f^{n}(x)= \frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(x-i)^{n+1}} - \frac{(-1)^n n!}{(x+i)^{n+1}}  \right]$$
Now we make the substitution using polar coordinates,

You'll notice this polar substitution generally made whenever you come across a $X^2+Y^2$ term present, here $X=x, Y=1$

$$x=r\cos\theta, 1=r\sin\theta, r=\sqrt{x^2+1}, \theta=cot^{-1}(x)$$
$$(x-i)^{n+1}=r^{n+1}(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)^{n+1}\implies ({x^2+1})^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta))^{n+1}$$
$$\implies ({x^2+1})^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(\cos(-(n+1)\theta)+i\sin(-(n+1)\theta))\tag1$$
$$(x+i)^{n+1}=r^{n+1}(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^{n+1}\implies ({x^2+1})^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^{n+1}$$
$$\implies ({x^2+1})^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(\cos((n+1)\theta)+i\sin((n+1)\theta))\tag2$$
Now coming back to $$f^{n}(x)= \frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(x-i)^{n+1}} - \frac{(-1)^n n!}{(x+i)^{n+1}}  \right]$$
$$f^{n}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n}n!}{2i} \left( \frac{(x+i)^{n+1}-(x-i)^{n+1}}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}\right)$$
Using $(1),(2)$,
$$(x+i)^{n+1}-(x-i)^{n+1}=2i\sin ((n+1)\theta)(1+x^2)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$$
I think you can take it from here, then its simple substituting and you'll get the answer as
$$\boxed{f^n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n\;n!}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^{n+1}}\sin\left((n+1)\cot^{-1}x\right)}$$

Refer here for further steps,


$$f^{n}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n}n!}{2i} \left( \frac{2i\sin ((n+1)\theta)(1+x^2)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}\right)$$


$$f^{n}(x)={(-1)^{n}n!}\left( \frac{\sin ((n+1)cot^{-1}(x))}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\right)$$


$$f^{n}(x)={(-1)^{n}n!}\left( \frac{\sin ((n+1)cot^{-1}x)}{(\sqrt{1+x^2})^{{n+1}}}\right)$$


$$f^n(x)=\frac{(-1)^n\;n!}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^{n+1}}\sin\left((n+1)\cot^{-1}x\right)$$

